# Por qué falla mi código de javascript cuando lo meto a una función pero si lo tengo dejo fuera de la función funciona perfectamente?

Tags: javascript, html

lo que intento hacer es que al presionar un boton se cargue el src de los tags img para eso hice una función en javascript pero no funciona, no obstante el mismo código funciona si no lo pongo en la función:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Imágenes </title>
</head>

<body >
    <div>
        <img class="imagen" />
        <img class="imagen" />

    </div>
    <form onclick="imagenes()">
            <input type="submit" value="Online Version">
    </form>
</body>
<script>
var carpeta="C:/Users/Sasuke/Documents/pagina/img/"
var images = ["img1.png", "img2.png"];
function imagenes(){
                var imagenes = document.getElementsByClassName("imagen");
                for(i = 0; i< images.length; i++){
                    var path=carpeta+images[i];
                    imagenes[i].setAttribute("src", path);
                }
                }

</script>
</html>
```

De esa forma no funciona, pero si quito la declaración de la función funciona bien, pero yo ocupo que ocurra solo cuando le doy click:

```
var carpeta="C:/Users/Sasuke/Documents/pagina/img/"
var images = ["img1.png", "img2.png"];

                var imagenes = document.getElementsByClassName("imagen");
                for(i = 0; i< images.length; i++){
                    var path=carpeta+images[i];
                    imagenes[i].setAttribute("src", path);
                }
```

Si el código de js lo dejo de esta manera si funciona y no entiendo ¿por qué? alguien puede ayudarme por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque en el primer código las variables carpeta e images quedan afuera de la función y por ende no pueden ser ocupadas por esta. Cuando llamas una función, sólo llamas a lo que está dentro de:

```
function imagenes(){
//Código
}
```

Por tanto, para que funcione el código debería ser así:

```
function imagenes(){
var carpeta="C:/Users/Sasuke/Documents/pagina/img/";
var images = ["img1.png", "img2.png"];

                var imagenes = document.getElementsByClassName("imagen");
                for(i = 0; i< images.length; i++){
                    var path=carpeta+images[i];
                    imagenes[i].setAttribute("src", path);
                }
}
```

Comment: Al estar definidas fuera de la funcion precisamente deberian ser globales y poder ser leidas sin problema